# How can I Extract Specific xml tags from a local xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, screen-scraping

I'm pretty new to interacting with xml, python, and scraping data so bear with me please:
I've got an xml file with my notes saved from evernote. I have been able to load BeautifulSoup and lxml into my python environment. I have also been able to load the xml file and print

Heres my code up until print:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
file = open('myNotes.xml','r')
data = file.read()
dom = parseString(data)
print data.toxml()
```

I didn't include the actual printed file as it contains lots of base 64 code.

What I am trying to accomplish is to extract select xml tags and print them to a new file... help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to use BeautifulSoup to print xml

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('myNotes.xml','r'))
print(soup.prettify())
```

And to write it to a file:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Now, to extract all of a certain type of tag to a list:

```
# Extract all of the <a> tags:    
tags = soup.find_all('a')
```

Comment: You don't have to `read()` on the file (`BeautifulSoup` takes a file pointer). Also, you may want to specify a better parser for xml. `soup = BeautifulSoup(open('myNotes.xml', 'r'), 'lxml')`

Comment: Thanks! that got it working, I was able to extract all the specific tags and print them to a new file.